# Prettier JSON on slack messages

Tags: json, slack

Is there a way to make JSON a bit more readable and less dull on Slack? When use simple 3 backticks, I just see:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slack has no detection and subsequent coloring of JSON within its code formatting for messages.

But you can have just if you send your JSON as "Code Snippet" via [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) instead of a message text. Make sure to set `filetype` to `javascript`.

Btw. this is the intended way for posting larger texts on Slack.